Can you use autodesk model derivatives api with the models stored in your own database?
I am working on a project where the user has an ability to upload both pictures and 3D models. I definitely want to have the pictures stored in my own backend without using Autodesk platform services. I am wondering if I can do the same for the models, while also utilizing the conversion features of the derivatives api?

Unfortunately Model Derivative cannot run out side of Autodesk Servers so you will need to upload the data, get it processed there.
